# Send email from Google spreadsheet in HTLM format?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to send email with data from Google Sheet but I want to look as is in spreadsheet. I know is should be in HTML format. I have `Template.html` with code but I don't know how write code to send email using that template. Please help.

I want send all date from one sheet. Is any one can wright that for me please. Whit explain what I have to change to work for me.

I wan to look the same formatting email as google spreadsheet[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJaGN.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHEnw.png)

Comment: This subject has been asked before.  Here is one response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71572262/send-only-team-members-data-in-email-using-google-appscript/71572726#71572726

Comment: Can you please share some example? what is the output format, or you just want to know about the API to send email from apps-script?

Comment: Hi i want to be look the same formatting on  email as google spreadsheet